# Passing Values from modal form to parent form vb.net

Tags: vb.net, modal-dialog, pass-by-reference

I am trying to pass information to parent form from modal form in vb.net winforms application.

1.) I created a copy of a form and displayed it using following code.

```
dim f=new frmParent()
f.show()
```

2.) Depending on conditions a button on frmParent opens a modal child form and asks for some informations. I used following code for that:

```
dim f = new ChildForm()
f.showDialog()
```

Both code works fine. When user press saves in child form i need to close childForm and use the user types values in parent form. I know how to close the childform but not sure how to pass info from childform to parent form.

Comment: you can have a public property on the child that the parent reads from as in David Steele's example; you can pass the child a reference to the main form and have it set a property or call a function on the parent form; you can have the parent pass a reference to something to hold the data, or a Func<> that can be called by the child to set the data; you can also have an event on the child form that the parent form attaches to prior to loading the child... probably others but those are the ones that come to mind first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a public property on your childForm

```
Public Property MyData As MyType
```

Then when you show the form you can do

```
dim f as new ChildForm()

If f.showDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
   Data = f.MyData()
End if
```

If you need to allow them to be able to edit that data again then you might also want to consider passing in the Data to the constructor of the dialog.

Comment: thnx... it worked gr8... I assumed since the child form has been already closed we won't be able to get values from its properties or variables....

Comment: Good news.  You can still access the forms public properties until your form variable (in this case f) goes out of scope.