# Passing value to parent from modal dialog

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am after a simple example/quick fix of passing a single value from dialog to asp parent page using JavaScript - if java script is best option that is!

I have made numerous attempts at doing this but failing with each effort so far.

lblVarSelectedDate.Text is the value i would like to post back to parent page to displayed as the lblVarChildSelectedDate value.

Below is part of Register.aspx page (PARENT)

```
    <table>
<tr>
      <td colspan="5" align="center"><asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text="Selected Date: "></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="lblVarChildSelectedDate" runat="server" ></asp:Label></td>
      <td colspan="1" align="center"><asp:Button ID="btnSelectDate" runat="server" Text="Date" /> </td>
</tr
<tr>
    <td><asp:Button ID="btOK" runat="server" Text="Ok" /> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This is the VB behind register.aspx...

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


End Sub

Sub btnSelectDate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnSelectDate.Click

    Dim Window As String
    Window = " window.open('About.aspx', 'MsgWindow', 'width=500, height=500');"

    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType, "date", Window, true)


End Sub

Sub btnOk_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btOK.Click

End Sub
```

And now her is my child page selectdate.aspx..

```
    <table>
<tr>
    <td colspan="6"><asp:Calendar ID="calSelecter" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="SelectionChange"></asp:Calendar></td>

</tr>
<tr>
      <td colspan="6" align="center"><asp:Label ID="lblConsSelectedDate" runat="server" Text="Selected Date: "></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="lblVarSelectedDate" runat="server" ></asp:Label></td>
</tr
<tr>
    <td><asp:Button ID="btOK" runat="server" Text="Ok" /> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Her is the vb behind the child page.

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    calSelecter.SelectedDate = Date.Today
    lblVarSelectedDate.Text = Date.Today

End Sub

Sub btnOk_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btOK.Click

    ' .... on click post back to parent page lblVarSelectedDate.Text 

End Sub

Sub SelectionChange(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    lblVarSelectedDate.Text = calSelecter.SelectedDate

End Sub
```

Many Thanks

Comment: I can't I am at work and this a problem I am having at home. A simple example would be appreciated..

Comment: You want to pass value as Querystring ?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what the best method is I am used to oo programming and would just use properties but can't figure out how I would do it in asp. So if that is what you would suggest would be the easiest way to pass a single value when the dialog is closed I'll give it a go.

Comment: search on google ! first answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020560/passing-values-from-modal-form-to-parent-form-vb-net

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911575/passing-variable-from-windows-form-to-modal

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20551203/how-to-get-values-from-a-dialog-form-in-vb-net

Comment: Want to use the var labelvalue that is is in the JavaScript on my asp page.

Comment: Specifically the value is equals to document.getElementById(labelname)

Answer (score 0):

One method is as follows:

1. In the parent create an element in the page that will contain the data
2. When opening the modal, pass a reference to the parent
3. In the modal use the reference to the parent page to access the element from step one and save the data in that element